# How to add background music in splash activty in cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I am creating new android application using cordova. I have used splash screen in the application that is working fine, but now I want to add some background music while splash screen is on. So how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different options. You could add an audio file directly into your `index.html` file and have it [autostart](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp) when it's finished decoding, but I *highly* recommend against that as it can create a poor experience for the user.

I would recommend adding audio in your javascript code with [howler.js](https://howlerjs.com) and then playing it after it's finished decoding && `deviceReady` has fired, that way it creates a much more consistent experience.

Comment: Wouldn't - at least for the second case - the audio only start after the splashscreen is already hidden? Isn't the `deviceready` event triggered after the app is fully initialized and thus the splashscreen got removed already?

Comment: @PatrickHübl-Neschkudla correct, but that way you would be able to have complete and consistent control over the audio playing. For example, I've done this to time my menu music for when the progress bar starts in all of my games

Comment: alright. Yeah, I was just wondering since the question is specifically about playing it during the splashscreen phase, which in this case would not work. I guess you'd have to create a custom plugin if there is none yet which would play the audio directly after the app is started.

Comment: I tried it with using howler.js but unfortunately it did not work. So I think I should create custom plugin for that.